# Console not see shared folder with PSexec

Tags: file-sharing, remote, psexec

The console execute T1.Bat to perfome a "dir U:*.*" on the Remote Device(PC1).
The device U is allocated on an other device connected in LAN with RC.
As you can see on the attached log, the commmand  "dir" doesn't matter.
But if I execute the batch T1 on the RC I see all files /directorys allocated on the remote U device.
Some suggestion?
Thanks

Update1: As you can see on the attached config, i have a LAN with 2 PC.
The folder F1 is allocated on the PC2 and is shared with PC1.
If I started T1.bat on the PC1 all files allocated on the folder F1 are displayed.
iF I stardet T1.bat with the console (like this command: *psexec \25.55.xxx.xxx -u Cxxx -p axxxx "D:\Dropbox\acasa\T1.bat" -nobanner -high* ) the command "dir" shows nothing (see Console attached)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpW8P.jpg)
[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxVCC.jpg)

Comment: so on your remote system you mapped a network drive as U:\, and then are trying to access that drive from a psexec remote shell, and you are trying to do it from a bat file. is that correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added in my post: Update#1

Comment: have you tried using `-i` with psexec? any difference?

Comment: Tried with -i without success.Thanks Frank

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED !!
With:
**net use I: \Servername\Sharename /user:username Password**
dir I:\

Where:
Servername=Name of the remote computer
Sharenname = Name of the folder shared
User & Password of the remote computer